# How to use F# to read a file into an in-memory collection?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, streamreader

I'm looking to try out F# to read a comma-delimited file into memory, de-duplicate it by one field, and write the results out to a pipe-separated file.

I've written an example of exactly what I want the program to do in C#:

```cs
        var input = new StreamReader(@"D:\input.txt");
        var addresses = new Dictionary<string, AddressModel>();

        while (!input.EndOfStream)
        {
            var address = new AddressModel(input);
            if (!addresses.ContainsKey(address.Id))
                addresses.Add(address.Id, address);
        }

        var output = new StreamWriter(@"D:\CSharp.txt");
        foreach (var address in addresses.Values)
        {
            output.WriteLine(address.ToString());
        }

        output.Flush();
```

With the AddressModel defined as:

```cs
    class AddressModel
    {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }

    public AddressModel(StreamReader inputStream)
    {
        if (inputStream == null) return;

        var input = inputStream.ReadLine();
        if (input == null) return;
        var split = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        Id = split[0];
        ZipCode = int.Parse(split[1]);
        StreetName = BuildStreet(split);
    }

    private string BuildStreet(string[] items)
    {
        var street = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[5]))
            street += items[5];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[6]))
            street += string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(street) ? items[6] : " " + items[6];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[7]))
            street += string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(street) ? items[7] : " " + items[7];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[8]))
            street += string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(street) ? items[8] : " " + items[8];
        return street;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", Id, StreetName, ZipCode);
    }
}
```

So what I'd like the program to do is read the file, line by line, use each line to construct a new AddressModel object, see if this item already exists in a dictionary, adding it if it doesn't, then write the contents of this dictionary to a second text file.

Of course, if I'm thinking "too object-oriented", and I can be doing this in a more functional manner, I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the main program like this:

```
open System 
let lines = IO.File.ReadLines @"D:\input.txt"
let addresses = new Dictionary<string, AddressModel>()
lines |> Seq.iter (fun line -> 
    let address = AddressModel line
    if not (addresses.ContainsKey address.Id) then
        addresses.Add (address.Id, address))
IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\CSharp.txt", Seq.map string addresses.Values)
```

As you can see the structure is not very different as what you had in C#, the difference is that instead of loops you can use higher order functions like `map` and `iter`

Then regarding your Address class you can re-use your C# class or write an F# function that parse each line:

```
let parseLine (input:string) =
    let split = input.Split [|','|]
    let id, zipCode = split.[0], Int32.Parse split.[1]
    let street = 
        split.[5..8] 
        |> Array.filter (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace >> not)
        |> String.concat " "
    (id, zipCode, street)

let printLine (id, zipCode, street) = sprintf "%s|%i|%s" id zipCode street
```

then you can update your main function like this:

```
open System 
let lines = IO.File.ReadLines @"D:\input.txt"
let addresses = new Dictionary<string, (string*int*string)>()
lines |> Seq.map parseLine |> Seq.iter (fun ((id,_,_) as line) -> 
    if not (addresses.ContainsKey id) then
        addresses.Add (id, line))

IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\CSharp.txt", Seq.map printLine addresses.Values)
```

Now you don't need the Dictionary step at all if its sole purpose is to get distinct ids. You can use `Seq.distinctBy` as suggested in the other answer. So your code will be further reduced to:

```
let lines = 
    IO.File.ReadLines @"D:\input.txt"
    |> Seq.map parseLine 
    |> Seq.distinctBy (fun (id,_,_) -> id)

IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\CSharp.txt", Seq.map printLine lines)
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the final code suggested:

```
open System 

let parseLine (input:string) =
    let split = input.Split [|','|]
    let id, zipCode = split.[0], Int32.Parse split.[1]
    let street = 
        split.[5..8] 
        |> Array.filter (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace >> not)
        |> String.concat " "
    (id, zipCode, street)

let printLine (id, zipCode, street) = sprintf "%s|%i|%s" id zipCode street

let lines = 
    IO.File.ReadLines @"D:\input.txt"
    |> Seq.map parseLine 
    |> Seq.distinctBy (fun (id,_,_) -> id)

IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\CSharp.txt", Seq.map printLine lines)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for this to be a starting point for a more complex parser, which would need to process each record in quite a complex manner, so something more class based would be good to help keep track of this.

Is there any chance you could show me how I'd go about implementing as in the C# example, with a strongly typed Address collection?

Comment: Yes @JamieS, I already did it. See the first code block, it uses your class as it is. You just need to translate your class to F# or keep it in C# if you prefer.

Comment: thanks @Gustavo, how would I go about translating the class to F#, with similar members?

Comment: @JamieS That should be a separate question, something like 'how would I translate this class to F#'. I would say try to translate it yourself first and if you have problems, post that question separately with the class code in C# and the F# code you came up but didn't work.

Comment: thanks, will do.

One last thing, using the code you've suggested the last line 
'IO.File.WriteAllLines(targetPath, Seq.map printLine lines)'
is erroring saying:
The type 'string * 'a * string' does not match the type 'string'

Any ideas?

Comment: @JamieS That's weird. I tested the code and compiles fine. May be you are  mixing a bit my suggestions. See the update, paste that code in a script and it which should compile perfectly, otherwise tell me.

Comment: Hi @JamieS may I ask you why did you un-tick my answer? Do you think something is missing. If so please tell me, I would be happy to modify it.

Comment: Hi @Gustavo - it wasn't the solution I ended up using for the performance test, because of the performance issues with Array.filter, and the Seq funcitons

Comment: OK @JamieS, then please add your solution. Other users would benefit from reading it. I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Seq.distinctBy` that works internally using a `Dictionary`.

```
type Contact = {Id:string; Name:string}
let lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\input.txt")

let output = 
        lines 
        |> Seq.map toContact
        |> Seq.distinctBy (fun c -> c.Id)
        |> Seq.map contactToStr

File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\CSharp.txt", output)
```

Saying you have a contact type, a function to build a contact from a string (`toContact`) and a function to build a string from a contact type (`contactToStr`), for instance:

```
let toContact (str:string) = 
        let values = str.Split(',')
        {Id = values.[0]; Name = values.[1]}
let contactToStr contact = sprintf "%s|%s" contact.Id contact.Name
```